# Figure with \input{tcilatex}?

Tags: graphics, compiling

I have this  files and the image do not appear why please?

I put in the document "tcilatex.tex" and the figure but the image do not appear only it's name How to do please .

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{cite,amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,amsfonts}


\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{10}


\input{tcilatex.tex}
\begin{document}


\begin{equation}
\FRAME{itbpFU}{4.715in}{4.715in}{0in}{\Qcb{Figure 1: A}}{}{%
figure1.jpg}{\special{language "Scientific Word";type
"GRAPHIC";maintain-aspect-ratio TRUE;display "USEDEF";valid_file "F";width
4.715in;height 4.715in;depth 0in;original-width 6.25in;original-height
6.25in;cropleft "0";croptop "1";cropright "1";cropbottom "0";filename
'Figure1.jpg';file-properties "XNPEU";}}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: not relevant to the question, but all the theorem-type objects, including definitions and remarks, will be set in italic, which is not traditional style.  `amsthm` has different, more appropriate, `\theoremstyle`s.  see the documentation (`texdoc amsthm`) for details.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3):

You could ask the person who provided this file to instead provide a version exported as portable latex but if it is just that image that is the problem, just replace by standard latex markup to include the `Figure1.jpg` that presumably came with the document.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{Figure1}
\caption{The graph $G$ for $n=4$}\end{figure}
\end{document}
```